# run command pipeline in C

Tags: c, strings, parsing, child-process, posix

This code parses and tokenizes my shell language command interpreter. I will try and make it 2 functions, one that is the tokenizer and the other that is the rest of the function. Can you find improvements that I can make besides breaking up the function into 2 smaller functions, with a helper function that is the tokenizer? Perhaps it can be done into 3 functions where the 3rd helper function can be the copying code for copying the `argv` variable.

Or even 4 different functions since this one can also be broken out (that strips leading whitespace)

```
        char * tmp = token;
        int x;
        while (*tmp == ' ') {
            *tmp++;
        }
        x = 0;
        while (*tmp != NULL) {
            token[x++] = *tmp++;
        }
        token[x] = '\0';
```

The whole function is:

```
static int runCmd(const char *cmd) {

    const char *cp;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    struct command shellcommand[4];
    const char **argv;
    int argc;
    int j;
    char *params[100];
    int i = 0;
    char *token;
    char **new_argv;

    for (cp = cmd; *cp; cp++) {
        if ((*cp >= 'a') && (*cp <= 'z'))
            continue;

        if ((*cp >= 'A') && (*cp <= 'Z'))
            continue;

        if (isDecimal(*cp))
            continue;

        if (isBlank(*cp))
            continue;

        if ((*cp == '.') || (*cp == '/') || (*cp == '-') ||
            (*cp == '+') || (*cp == '=') || (*cp == '_') ||
            (*cp == ':') || (*cp == ',') || (*cp == '\'') ||
            (*cp == '"')) {
            continue;
        }

    }

    makeArgs(cmd, &argc, &argv);
    token = strtok(cmd, "|");
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    params[0] = NULL;
    while (token != NULL) {
        char * tmp = token;
        int x;
        while (*tmp == ' ') {
            *tmp++;
        }
        x = 0;
        while (*tmp != NULL) {
            token[x++] = *tmp++;
        }
        token[x] = '\0';
        makeArgs(token, &argc, &argv);
        /* Will copy argc characters */
        new_argv = malloc((argc + 1) * sizeof *new_argv);
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
            size_t length = strlen(argv[i]) + 1;
            new_argv[i] = malloc(length);
            memcpy(new_argv[i], argv[i], length);
        }
        new_argv[argc] = NULL;
        shellcommand[i].argv = new_argv;
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, "|");
    }
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork failed");
        return -1;
    }
    /*
     * If we are the child process, then go execute the program.
     */
    if (pid == 0) {
        /* spawn(cmd);*/
        fork_pipes(i, shellcommand);
    }
    /*
     * We are the parent process.
     * Wait for the child to complete.
     */
    status = 0;
    intCrlf = FALSE;

    while (((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) && (errno == EINTR));

    intCrlf = TRUE;

    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error from waitpid: %s", strerror(errno));

        return -1;
    }

    if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pid %ld: killed by signal %d\n",
                (long) pid, WTERMSIG(status));

        return -1;
    }

    return WEXITSTATUS(status);
}
```

### Update

I have made a refactoring to make it smaller. I have broken out the `trim leading whitespace` to a function.

```
char * trimstring(char * token, int operation) {
    char * tmp = token;
    int x;
    while (*tmp == ' ') {
        *tmp++;
    }
    x = 0;
    while (*tmp != NULL) {
        token[x++] = *tmp++;
    }
    token[x] = '\0';
    return token;
}


static int runCmd(const char *cmd) {
    const char *cp;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    struct command shellcommand[4];
    const char **argv;
    int argc;
    int i = 0;
    char *token;
    char **new_argv;
    for (cp = cmd; *cp; cp++) {
        if ((*cp >= 'a') && (*cp <= 'z'))
            continue;

        if ((*cp >= 'A') && (*cp <= 'Z'))
            continue;

        if (isDecimal(*cp))
            continue;

        if (isBlank(*cp))
            continue;

        if ((*cp == '.') || (*cp == '/') || (*cp == '-') ||
            (*cp == '+') || (*cp == '=') || (*cp == '_') ||
            (*cp == ':') || (*cp == ',') || (*cp == '\'') ||
            (*cp == '"')) {
            continue;
        }

    }
    makeArgs(cmd, &argc, &argv);
    token = strtok((char *) cmd, "|");
    i = 0;
    while (token != NULL) {
        token  = trimstring(token, 0);
        makeArgs(token, &argc, &argv);
        /* Will copy argc characters */
        new_argv = malloc((argc + 1) * sizeof *new_argv);
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
            size_t length = strlen(argv[i]) + 1;
            new_argv[i] = malloc(length);
            memcpy(new_argv[i], argv[i], length);
        }
        new_argv[argc] = NULL;
        shellcommand[i].argv = new_argv;
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, "|");
    }
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork failed");
        return -1;
    }
    /* If we are the child process, then go execute the program.*/
    if (pid == 0) {
        /* spawn(cmd);*/
        fork_pipes(i, shellcommand);
    }
    /*
     * We are the parent process.
     * Wait for the child to complete.
     */
    status = 0;
    while (((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) && (errno == EINTR));
    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error from waitpid: %s", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pid %ld: killed by signal %d\n",
                (long) pid, WTERMSIG(status));

        return -1;
    }
    return WEXITSTATUS(status);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, why aren't you using ctype.h which defines isalpha(), isspace(), isnumber()?

Comment: @pacmaninbw I forgot about it. I'm new to this detailed level of C. I come from Java and Python.

Comment: Instead of malloc() and memcpy() use string.h and strdup(). Does they same thing and is optimized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Memory leaks

Since this is part of a shell and can therefore be considered an extension of the OS which should not stop at any point, you have a memory leak problem. Unlike Java and Python there is no garbage collection, you have to manage the memory on your own. Any `malloc()` calls you make either explicitly or implicitly with functions such as `strdup()` need corresponding calls to `free()`. You need to clean up `new_argv`. This will need to be a loop that calls `free()` for each of the arguments in `new_argv` and then `free()` `new_argv itself`. See this [question](//programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/113177/why-do-languages-such-as-c-and-c-not-have-garbage-collection-while-java-does) on Programmers SE.

### Use the standard library when possible

It appears you have written your own functions `isDecimal()`, `isBlank()` rather than using the standardized functions such as `isalpha()` (defined in the for loop), `isspace()` (finds all white space, not just blank) and `strdup()`. There are a number of character functions in `ctype.h` that can help, and `string.h` will provide the definitions of `strdup()`, `strcpy()`, `strcmp()` and `strlen()` which will also help.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
```

If you're on a Linux system try `man ctype` and `man strdup`.

Your for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
    size_t length = strlen(argv[i]) + 1;
    new_argv[i] = malloc(length);
    memcpy(new_argv[i], argv[i], length);
}
```

becomes simply

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    new_argv[i] = strdup(argv[i]);
}
```